# Oracle SQL Invalid Identifier for Column that Exists

Tags: sql, oracle, grails

I'm working on converting a directory search project to draw its data from an oracle sql database. I keep getting  an error that I don't know what to do with, and Google isn't being helpful.
It's the WHERE clause throwing the errors:

```
SELECT BID as ada_id, DEPARTMENT as ada_name, BOX_ADDR as ada_box, OFFICE_PHONE as
ada_phone,FAX_NUMBER as ada_fax, ACU_EMAIL as ada_email, BLDG_ROOM as ada_bldg_room 
FROM [view]
Where BID = ${id}
```

The error says "Grails tag [sitemesh:captureBody] was not closed." What does this mean? How do I fix it?

Thank you.

EDIT: I got it solved. Thanks everyone who tried to help!

Comment: oracle or mysql  ... show the correct tag

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean. Show the correct tag for what? Where?

Comment: i don't understand how SQL Developer can execute a query with `ada_id` in the WHERE clause. If `[view]` doesn't contain a column of that name, we expect the ORA-00904 error. (It's not allowed to reference (in the WHERE clause) an alias assigned to an expression in the SELECT list (of the same SELECT statement). We can reference ada_id in GROUP BY or a HAVING clause, but it's not allowed in the WHERE clause. (And making that valid would require a non-standard extension which could break existing SQL e.g. `SELECT a AS b FROM ( SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b FROM dual )  v WHERE b = 2`  (which b?)

Comment: you have choose tag mysql  and grails ..but you question is for oracle   so you should update your question and  add the proper  tag .. you can see  the tags extreme  left side you name  (above Thank you)

Comment: You're right, thanks. Now I understand that error.

Comment: You error seems to coming from a gsp?  Are you putting SQL code in gsp.  This should be in a service that would be called from a Controller and then return to the view (gsp).

Comment: How do you know it's coming from a gsp? (I'm asking so I'll know next time I see whatever you're seeing.) I'm not seeing any SQL in the gsp. To be sure I'm understanding you right, are you saying a controller should call a service that has the sql code then this service should return a gsp?

Comment: Since the error was about sitemesh and sitemesh is a View layout technology and the Grail view technology is gsp.  Also the way your formatted the ${id} looks like how you reference a GSP model varaible. Where are you getting this error?

Comment: Please post the code not just the SQL statement that might help shed like on what is happening.